# How do I know what options are being passed to GCC from CMake?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

I am trying to build a large open-source project (Clang) that uses CMake in its build system. I am using MinGW64 on Windows.

The command to build is:

```
cmake --build . --config Debug --target clang
```

I am having problems with the build so I would like to diagnose what commands are being sent to GCC. For example, I would like to know if `-g` is set.

How can I see the list of GCC commands that a CMake build triggers?

Comment: Just open the makefile and see.

Comment: @IvanRubinson The makefile CMake generated for LLVM+clang3.8 on my system has more than 9400 lines. So have fun with that. XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VERBOSE=1 make | more`

example:

```
[ 14%] Building CXX object public_api/CMakeFiles/secr_api_tests.dir/tests/exception_test.cpp.o
cd /Users/rhodges/secr/netbeans-secr/public_api && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -I/Users/rhodges/secr/secr/public_api/src -I/Users/rhodges/secr/netbeans-secr/public_api/src -I/Users/rhodges/secr/secr/public_api/tests -I/Users/rhodges/secr/netbeans-secr/public_api/tests -isystem /Users/rhodges/secr/secr/public_api/include -isystem /Users/rhodges/secr/netbeans-secr/public_api/include -isystem /Users/rhodges/secr/netbeans-secr/target_local/include -isystem /Users/rhodges/secr/secr/valuelib/debug/include -isystem /Users/rhodges/secr/netbeans-secr/valuelib/debug/include -isystem /Users/rhodges/secr/secr/valuelib/data/include -isystem /Users/rhodges/secr/netbeans-secr/valuelib/data/include -isystem /Users/rhodges/secr/secr/valuelib/tuple/include -isystem /Users/rhodges/secr/netbeans-secr/valuelib/tuple/include -isystem /Users/rhodges/secr/secr/valuelib/immutable/include -isystem /Users/rhodges/secr/netbeans-secr/valuelib/immutable/include -isystem /Users/rhodges/secr/secr/valuelib/stdext/include -isystem /Users/rhodges/secr/netbeans-secr/valuelib/stdext/include  -std=gnu++14 -o CMakeFiles/secr_api_tests.dir/tests/exception_test.cpp.o -c /Users/rhodges/secr/secr/public_api/tests/exception_test.cpp
...
```

Comment: Not exactly sexism. I'd say *command-ism*!! What against `VERBOSE=1 make | less`? Do not discriminate it. :-)

Comment: @skypjack typing `more` is a 30-year-old habit :) I was using unix when `vi` was considered to be state of the art...

Comment: Isn't it anymore nowadays? I'm still trying to quit it and I've never been updated about the world out of there!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

As Richard Hodges said, `VERBOSE=1 make` is the main handy way to do it.

Another is to add `-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON` to your CMake call, which will generate a file `compile_commands.json` with a machine-readable database of compilation flags per file.